# Apache error AH01630 (client denied) but working

Tags: php, apache

I have got something strange here.
I have an API working on https://mydomain.test/rest.php

Everything goes well but for each call to my API, there is a new line in my apache error.log.
Example: call GET "https://mydomain.test/rest.php/Test"

It works, but add this line in the apache error.log:

`[Wed Sep 09 09:44:07.843001 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 16908] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:64482] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/myproject/front/Test`

My project is located at /var/www/html/myproject.

Here is my apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin support@mydomain.test
    ServerName mydomain.test

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/front

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/mychain.crt


    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>


    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown


    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject/front/>
        Require all denied

        <Files rest.php>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

While searching for solution I found some people having same trouble, but every solutions mentioned was to ignore the line, or reduce the log level (this is not an option in my case ;).

I noticed that apache is stripping the "rest.php" from the path, but i can't figured it out. Why is this happened?

Thanks all!

Comment: I'm using apache 2.4.7